# VS 2019 16.11.7(last release) how to return white color in editor?

Tags: visual-studio

I've been updated my VS 2019 pro to latest update, and now I want to return back white color in editor for '=' symbol... because as you can see it's impossible to see something in Dark theme... can anyone help me with how to do it? because I didn't find in settings anything what can help...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Bp4O.png)

Comment: What happens when you press `Use Defaults` in the `Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colours` page?

Answer (score 0):

Try this `file > preferences > color theme`  and then pick up a light theme.

[image]